# Firebase: how to re-authenticate using UserCredential

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

When the users signs in with email/password for the first time, I store the firebase's `UserCredential` as a json string using:

```
private afAuth: AngularFireAuth;
...
this.afAuth.auth
   .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then((userCredential: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
      // serialize it as json
      var credentialJson = JSON.stringify(userCredential);

      // store it on device
      this.settings.setValue(this.USER_CREDENTIALS_KEY, credentialJson)
   });
```

Now, suppose that the user shuts down the app and the next day opens up the app. I want to use the credentials to auto-authenticate the user. So I deserialize that json string to a firebase's `UserCredential` and try to re-authenticate the user using:

```
this.settings.getValue(this.USER_CREDENTIALS_KEY)
   .then((result: string) => {
       // json-deserialize it from device
       let userCredential: firebase.auth.UserCredential = JSON.parse(result);

       // use credential to authenticate the user
       this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(userCredential.credential)
          .then((credential: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
            console.log("Successfully signed in");
      })
   });
```

But `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` never succeeds. The error messages are in line with 'The token has been expired' or 'invalid user credential' or 'the user doesn't exist'

The whole point of this exercise is that I don't want to store email/password (or even a hash of it on the user's device for obvious reasons) to re-use them for re-authenticating the user each time he/she runs the app.

Furthermore if I can re-use the `UserCredential` object to auto-re-authenticate the user then no matter what the sign-in method was (i.e. email/password, google, facebook, etc.) I can always re-authenticate the user using one method.

p.s. I tried using tokens `i.e this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(userToken)` but no luck with that one either. The good point about token is that token is a string and I don't even need to json serialize/deserialize the `UserCredential` object.

Comment: Never store plain text passwords on a device. Firebase Auth sessions are indefinite. The user will remain sign in. If they need to reauthenticate, you have to ask the user for the password again.

Comment: So the only thing that I can think of, for now, is to store `uid` of the user on the database and next time that the user opens up the app, I would check if their uid exists in the database. This is a very fragile workaround though.